# Approximate the integral $I(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\cos \left ( x\left ( t^2-t^4 \right ) \right )dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, approximation, approximate-integration

At $x\to \infty $ approximate the integral
$$I(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\cos \left ( x\left ( t^2-t^4 \right ) \right )dt$$

**My attempt:**

$$f(t) = t^2-t^4\Rightarrow f'(t) = 2t - 4t^3 = 2t(1 - 2t^2) = 0$$

I've tried to break it down in Taylor's row
$$
\cos(xf(t))\sim \cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}f'(t_1)\sin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\cdot (t-t_1)+O((t-t_1)^2).
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
I(x)&\sim\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\cos \left (\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)dt-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}f'(t_1)\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }(t-t_1)\sin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)(t^2-t^4)dt\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\cos \left (\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}f'(t_1)\left(\frac{3}{x^3}-\frac{15}{x^5}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\cos \left (\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2x}+\frac{15\sqrt{2}}{4x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$

Have I made the right decision? If so, what should I do next?

Comment: I would recommend checking your approximation and numerical solution to your integral for many values of x, using mathematica

Comment: I'd like to solve this with my hands

Comment: Then type it into mathematica with your hands...jk :). Seriously, though, don't underestimate the power of checking your work numerically; it will tell you instantly if you have made some sort of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For positive values of $x$
$$I(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\cos \left ( x\left ( t^2-t^4 \right ) \right )\,dt$$is such that
$$\frac{4 \sqrt{2}}{\pi }\,I(x)=\sin \left(\frac{x+3 \pi}{8} \right)
   J_{-\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x}{8}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{x+\pi
   }{8}\right) J_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{x}{8}\right)$$ (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BCos%5Bx+%28t%5E2+-+t%5E4%29%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%2CAssumptions-%3Ex%3E0%5D))

Expanding the trignonometric functions and later using double angle formulae, for large value of $x$
$$\large\color{blue}{I(x)=\frac{1}{2}  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}}\left(    P(x)\,\cos \left(\frac{x}{4}\right)+Q(x)\,\sin \left(\frac{x}{4}\right)+\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}P(x)\right)}$$

where
$$P(x)=1-\frac{3}{4 x}-\frac{105}{32 x^2}+\frac{3465}{128 x^3}+O\left (\frac {1} {x^4} \right)$$
$$Q(x)=1+\frac{3}{4 x}-\frac{105}{32 x^2}-\frac{3465}{128 x^3}+O\left (\frac {1} {x^4} \right)$$

This is a very good approximation even for quite low value of $x$. For example, using $x=100$, the exact value is $0.13752183$ while the above approximation gives  $\color{red}{0.137521}47$.

Comment: I assume you also used [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17.E3). If you did, it may be mentioned.

Comment: @Gary. No, I did not. As we say in French, I just reinvented the warm water. Cheers. :-)

Comment: And how did you get the decomposition through a Bessel function? Can you explain this point?

Comment: @Partim. As Gary wrote in comments, have a look at   https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17#E3

Comment: What kind of decomposition should I look at? Under which number?

Comment: @Partim. $10.17.3$

Comment: I don't quite understand how this decomposition of the Bessel function 10.17.3 helped to decompose the integral ?